# Alignment of absolute position \textblock (left/right problem)

Tags: alignment, textpos

Im able to put to an absolute position of a page, a certain text. In this example:

- text width is 4cm
- the absolute position is from the top left corner, 5cm xshift and -2cm yshift.

> ```
> \documentclass[11pt,a4]{article} 
> \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
> \usepackage[left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm]{geometry}
> \textblockorigin{0mm}{297mm}
>
>
> \begin{document} 
> blabla
>   
> \begin{textblock*}{4cm}(5cm,-27.7cm){
> \noindent text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
> }\end{textblock*}
>   
> \end{document}
> ```

it does this:

[image]

[image]

How can I control the alignment? I want, that the textblock makes an alignment like this:

[image]

Comment: As always on this site: you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Here we have to add code in order to even test your example.

Comment: That said aren't the box 4cm wide? And thus when it is placing relative to the upper left hand corner, the x coord of that point is `5cm - 4cm`

Comment: @daleif i edited my post

Comment: I changed the `align` tag to `alignment`.  `align` is specific to a multi-line math display environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{textblock}` environment has an option to indicate the ‘reference point’ of the block.  In the example below, I've added `[1,0]` to indicate that it's the top-right of the textblock that is to be located at `(5cm,-27.7cm)`.  That means that TeX does the corresponding arithmetic, not you.

Your question also asked about right-aligning the contents.  pascal974's use of the `{flushright}` environment is right, `\raggedright` works, too.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4]{article} 
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage[left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm]{geometry}
\textblockorigin{0mm}{297mm}


\begin{document} 
blabla

\begin{textblock*}{4cm}[1,0](5cm,-27.7cm){
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\raggedleft\par % force a new paragraph, so TeX 'notices' the \raggedleft
}\end{textblock*}
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: i didnt want to use raggedleft or flushright. That was pascal's idea. I just wanted, that textblock indicates the right top corner, which you answered. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

As I already told you just subtract 4cm from the 5cm!

The tikz code is just to show where everything is

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage[left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm]{geometry}
\textblockorigin{0mm}{297mm}

% just to specify where things are, and an alternative to textpos
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\noindent
blabla
  
%\begin{textblock*}{4cm}(5cm,-27.7cm)
\begin{textblock*}{4cm}(1cm,-27.7cm)
\noindent text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
\end{textblock*}

% requires several compilations
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \coordinate (A) at ($(current page.north west)+(0,-2)$);
  \coordinate (B) at ($(current page.north west)+(5,0)$);
  \coordinate (C) at ($(current page.north west)+(5,-2)$);
  \fill[red] (A) circle (1mm);
  \fill[red] (B) circle (1mm);
  \fill[red] (C) circle (1mm);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `flushright` environment

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
% \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,showframe]{geometry}
\textblockorigin{0mm}{297mm}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document} 

%\tikz \draw[red](0,0)rectangle(5,-2);

blabla
\begin{textblock*}{4cm}(1cm,-27.7cm){
    \begin{flushright}
        \noindent text  text
    \end{flushright}
}\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```